# NLTK importError when using Porter Stemmer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, importerror, porter-stemmer

I am importing nltk, but it gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/control/Work/Intelligence/Datasets/whats cooking/new.py", line 4, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk-3.0.5-py2.7.egg/nltk/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk-3.0.5-py2.7.egg/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk-3.0.5-py2.7.egg/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 25, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import porter
ImportError: cannot import name porter
```

My nltk was working perfectly a few days ago and i haven't updated or changed anything and I've also installed all the nltk data.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic use of Porter stemmer in NLTK (see http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html) would be:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> sent = 'I went on wild geese chases'
>>> porter.stem(sent)
u'I went on wild geese chas'
```

**Note:** that `PorterStemmer` don't work very well with irregular plurals

Take a look at:

- [Stemmers vs Lemmatizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers)
- [lemmatize plural nouns using nltk and wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016540/lemmatize-plural-nouns-using-nltk-and-wordnet)
- [Python NLTK Lemmatization of the word 'further' with wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999273/python-nltk-lemmatization-of-the-word-further-with-wordnet)